# Clearing a libGDX pixmap

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way to clear a libGDX `Pixmap`? Or is the only way to dispose it and create a brand new Pixmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by clear you mean set all the pixels to transparent you could do the bellow.

```
Pixmap.setColor(Color.CLEAR);
Pixmap.fill()
```

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#fill--
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.html